# android - display fixed image grid (with a TableLayout?)

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-tablelayout, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to display a grid of images (I know at execution time how many they would be). My problem is that this grid must be inside a vertical ScrollView and inside a ViewPager, so it's discouraged to place two scrollable views one inside the other, and I can't use an horizontal GridLayout because I'm in a ViewPager so the horizontal scrolling is already cought.
[image: I want to do this]

So I'm trying to achieve this using TableLayout and setting manually all paddings/margins/dimensions by using some math. What I'm getting is this:
[image: my test]

Is there something that I can do to achieve these results?

Probably using a GridLayout with fixed height and width..

The code I've written till now to populate the TableLayout is reported below. It's in a Fragment, "act" is the reference to the activity, table_view is my TableLayout, objectids is a LinkedList containing the ids of the images to use.

```
private void calculateGrid() {
    table_view.removeAllViews();
    table_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    int minLato = Math.min(act.metrics.widthPixels, act.metrics.heightPixels);

    float density = act.metrics.density;
    int screenX = (int) (minLato / act.metrics.density);
    float factor = 4f;
    int imageXpx = (int) (minLato / factor);
    int imageX = (int) (imageXpx / act.metrics.density);

    int margins;
    int numImage = objectids == null ? 0 : objectids.size();
    int numRow;
    int numCol;
    int gridY; // = ?
    int countImg = 1;

    if (screenX % imageX == 0) { // TODO poi sarà un po piu di 0 per non avere margini minuscoli
        numCol = screenX / imageX - 1;
        margins = imageX / (screenX / imageX);
    } else {
        numCol = screenX / imageX;
        margins = (screenX % imageX) / (screenX / imageX + 1);
    }

    margins = Math.min(10, margins);

    int dpMargins = (int) (margins * density);

    numRow = (int) Math.ceil(numImage / (double) numCol);

    gridY = numRow * (margins * 2 + imageX);

    Log.e(TAG, "dens: " + density + " screen: " + screenX + " img: " + imageX + " margins: " + margins + " numImg: " + numImage + " numRow: " + numRow
            + " numCol" + numCol + " gridY: " + gridY);

    List<TableRow> rows = new LinkedList<TableRow>();
    int ID = 1000;
    TableRow oneRow;

    TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tableParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

    for (int i = 1; i <= numRow; i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "row " + i);
        oneRow = new TableRow(ctx);
        oneRow.setLayoutParams(tableParams);
        for (int k = 1; k <= numCol; k++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "col " + k);
            if (countImg <= numImage) {
                Log.i(TAG, "img " + countImg);
                ImageView img = new ImageView(ctx);

                TableRow.LayoutParams rp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(imageXpx, imageXpx);
                rp.bottomMargin = dpMargins;
                rp.topMargin = dpMargins;
                rp.leftMargin = dpMargins;
                rp.rightMargin = dpMargins;

                img.setLayoutParams(rp);
                img.setId(ID + countImg);

                img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                loadBitmaps(ctx, app.getDatabase(), img, objectids.get(countImg - 1), "image", target_graphid, ticket);

                img.setImageResource(R.drawable.capiicona);
                oneRow.addView(img);
                countImg++;
            }
        }
        rows.add(oneRow);
    }

    for (TableRow tr : rows)
        table_view.addView(tr);

    table_view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)

}
```

Thanks for your precious help.